# Can I enter the USA after my H1B visa start date?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My H1B visa got approved, however, I haven’t received my passport yet (10 days later). After many calls and emails I finally went to the embassy again and I was told that there are some governmental/administrative issues and it might take up to one month for the visa to be stamped in my passport (but they confirmed again it was approved). Given that, I will most probably have to go to the US after my start date. Of course I emailed my employer about it but I wanted to ask if anyone knows what would happen in this situation? Can I enter US after my start date, given that the delay is not because of me (and it should be easy to prove the timeline of the passport return process if needed)? Should I expect for the start date to be delayed by my employer? Thank you!

Comment: "there are some governmental/administrative issues and it might take up to one month for the visa to be stamped in my passport" — are you sure the visa is finally approved, and you're not sent to the administrative processing (better known as SAO; Security Advisory Opinion)? If it's the latter, it may take from weeks to years, and you've probably got requested some extra documents like CV.

Comment: @yeputons when I checked on the US Department of State page, it says clearly "Approved". Then below it says "Your visa is in final processing. If you have not received it in more than 10 working days, please see the webpage...". So I would say it is approved. But I have never heard of SAO, so could it be that if it says Approved?

Comment: The status on the website is typically either "rejected" or "under [administrative processing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104146/221g-administrative-processing-is-this-a-refusal-denial?rq=1)" with SAO, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

> Given that, I will most probably have to go to the US after my start date.

Yes. You cannot enter the US without your passport and visa in hand.

> Of course I emailed my employer about it but I wanted to ask if anyone knows what would happen in this situation?

You just have to sit tight and wait it out. You employer needs to delay your official start date until you can legally allowed to work in the country.

> Can I enter US after my start date,

Yes

> given that the delay is not because of me

That's irrelevant

> Should I expect for the start date to be delayed by my employer?

That's the only viable option. While it's frustrating and infuriating for all parties, that's the way the US government works. Most companies that are hiring with H1Bs are used to that type of delay and will deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can most definitely enter after the start date of your visa, and your actual start date will probably be adjusted by the employer to when you can come to the office (unless they allow remote work).

Comment: Thank you for this! I was not sure if changing the start date is possible, given that when I applied for the visa I declared the original start date (which is now impossible). I was not sure if that can cause an issue. Actually my work is remote (it is a major software engineering company that allows that - it would have been mainly remote even if I was in the USA). However, can I actually start working remotely outside the USA? Won't there be issues with taxes and stuff (although I already rented a place in the US so my residency now is officially in the US)?

Comment: @user132187 that may create some complications for you and the employer since you'll be working in your home country and the employer would need to comply with the local laws and regulations - not every employer would want that, especially if you're a singleton.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not enter the US after your "visa start date", but only because US Visas don't have a start date!

US visas have an "Issue Date" and an "Expiration Date".  You can use your visa to enter the US any time between when it is issued to you, and the expiration date.

Given you are on a work visa, there is an additional requirement that you may not enter the country more than a certain number of days BEFORE you are due to start working (it's 10 days for some visas, but I'm not sure for H-1B), however there are no corresponding rules for entering after your intended start date.

Comment: H1b visas do in fact have a "visa start date", It's Oct 1st of the year, or the employment start date if later, and you cannot start working before that date or enter the country 10 days before that date (IIRC)

Comment: @littleadv An employment start date, yes.  Not a visa start date. The fact you can enter 10 days beforehand makes that fairly clear (if it was a visa start date, you'd be entering before the visa started, which makes no sense!)

Comment: 10 days before Oct 1st, not 10 days before visa was issued, if it wasn't clear. For H1b specifically "start date" is an actual thing. You are right about most other visa types, but not about H1b.

Comment: @Doc thank you! Do you have any idea of what happens in terms of the employment itself? Will the start date of the employment be delayed until I am able to come to the USA? Also is working remotely (which is possible in my case) an option before entering the USA, or should I expect to not be allowed to work until I am present in the USA (even if the work is still remote).

Comment: Starting your answer with 'no' gives a different message than the body of the answer. Better rewrite it, as many people will read no further than the first word.

Comment: @user132187 no, the start of employment will be as contracted with the company employing you. Obviously it will mean you cannot honour your commitment to start at that date so will have to contact them to see what you need to do. Most likely they will accommodate you because the delay isn't your fault, but it may well cost you money in lost wages for the delay period.

Comment: @littleadv Perhaps you can provide a photo of a H-1B showing this apparently VISA start date?

Comment: @Doc It's a known constant, it's not necessarily written on a visa (although sometimes it is noted in the annotations). It's OK if you learned something new today.

Comment: See for example [here](https://www.nnuimmigration.com/h1b-visa-processing-time-duration/), look for "H1B visa timings".

Comment: @littleadv the critical date here is the start date of the petition's period of validity, shown at the top of the I-129, not on the visa.  The employee cannot arrive more than ten days before that date.

Comment: @phoog not sure how that would make Doc's answer correct. If the H1b visa was issued in May it doesn't mean that the OP can enter the country using it in August, the OP would still have to wait till no earlier than Sept. 20, so Doc's answer is absolutely wrong. If you want to say that the date is not explicitly printed on the visa and is instead printed on some other document - I'm not arguing otherwise, but it's irrelevant to both the question and the answer.

Comment: And BTW, the receipt number (which is the identifier of that I-129) is most definitely printed on the visa.

Comment: @littleadv it's correct perhaps only in the trivial and literal sense that all US visas are valid from the moment they're issued.  An H-1B worker needs more than a valid visa to enter the US (there are other nonimmigrant categories for which this is true, as you no doubt know).  The worker also needs a valid petition or one that will become valid within ten days.  All the talk about October 1st and the employment start date is irrelevant; what matters is the date on the I-129. Whether this date is October 1st or another date, delaying the start of employment won't change it.

Comment: So, suppose user132187 was supposed to start on January 15th and has a petition valid from January 15th and was planning to arrive on January 5th but doesn't get the visa until February 15th.  The petition and the visa are both valid, so the company and the employee can arrange whatever start date they want, even one that is more than 10 days after arrival.